# How to Create Search Service Application using PowerShell in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

SharePoint 2019 Search Service Application is showing Error and the service is not getting started,

***Error:-
The Search Service is not able to connect to the machine that host Administration components, Verify the administration component "GUID" in Search Application is in a good state and try Again***

Tried Below Steps but nothing works

1. Component Refresh:-

- $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application"
- $ssa.RefreshComponents()

2. Service Provisioning:-

- $service = Get-SPServiceInstance -Identity 7649ed8f-a46c-4a69-a79b-9a153b9f1fd2
- $service.provision()
- $service.update()
- iisreset /noforce

3. Remove Search Application:-

- $ssa = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name 'Search Service Application'
- Remove-SPServiceApplication $ssa
  While Removing the Search Application it got struck for more than 2 hours, then i need to restarted the timer Service until it completes the process, looks wired

4. Creating the Search Service Application:-

- $appPool = get-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity 'SharePoint Web Services Default'
- New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name "Search Service Application" -ApplicationPool $appPool

I need to restarted the timer Service until it completes the process, looks wired.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ where I'm a mod :)